# Adding JSON attributes using Python?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to combine data using Python. For an example, I want to combine

```
[{'foo': 'something'}, {'foo': 'something else'}, {'foo': 'something else'}]
```

and

```
[{'bar': 'else'}, {'bar': 'else else'}, {'bar': 'else else'}]
```

to something like this:

```
[{'foo: 'something', 'bar': 'else'}, {'foo': 'something else', 'bar': 'else else'}, {'foo': 'something else', 'bar': 'else else'}]
```

Would this be possible in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is produce a new dictionary for each two input dictionaries. Use `zip()` to produce pairs:

```
result = [dict(a, **b) for a, b in zip(first, second)]
```

where `first` and `second` are your input lists. `dict()` creates a copy of an existing dictionary, but the `**b` syntax is a bit of a trick to add additional keys.

Answer (score 1):

The result will be in **a**

```
a = [{'foo': 'something'}, {'foo': 'something else'}, {'foo': 'something else'}] 
b = [{'bar': 'else'}, {'bar': 'else else'}, {'bar': 'else else'}]
for i,j in zip(a,b):
     i.update(j)
print a
```

Comment: This updates the first list in-place. Note that the `i = None` assignment is entirely redundant here. @user3587412: I'm fine with this if this answer helped you most, but you cannot mark *both* answers as helpful. It is one or the other only. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters- you are correct , being java guy used to of initializing variables.